# How do I find a Canadian address that appears to go missing between Censuses?

Tags: 20th-century, canada, census-records, 1920s

I'm looking for a record for 426 Clinton Street, Toronto in the 1921 Census. In the 1911 Census this was Toronto West, Ward 5, Sub-District 65. The 400 block is north of Bloor Street, but only south is included in the Toronto West listing. Ward 5, Sub-District 65 is also in Toronto North but doesn't include Clinton Street.

How might I track this address down in the 1921 census?

Comment: Welcome to GFH-SE!  Your question is very specific which is good but at the same time very localized in geography which means an answer to it may not help many others.  I would probably phrase it more along the lines of "How do I find a Canada address that appears to go missing between Censuses?" and then give your specific example.

Comment: Cindy, I've generalised your question as suggested by @PolyGeo but retained the specific information that interests you.

Answer (score 6):

Finding streets in the Canada 1921 Census (especially for Toronto) has been discussed in [an earlier question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3645/street-index-for-canada-1921-census).

As I wasn't able to find a street index, I compilied a partial one from the descriptions Ancestry supplied for some subdistricts.  It doesn't include streets where the subdistrict contains more than one polling subdivision, which is especially common in Toronto North.  Still, it's better than nothing. As mentioned in my answer to my question there, this partial index is [available on Github](https://github.com/robhoare/census1921/blob/master/index/combined-toronto-city.txt).  Improvements and corrections welcome!

It contains the following entries for Clinton St:

```
Clinton St. both sides, from Mansfield avenue to College Street: Sub-District 41 - Ward 5   : Toronto West
Clinton Street, both sides, from College to Harbord Street: Sub-District 57 - Ward 5   : Toronto West
Clinton Street, east side, from Harbord to Bloor Street: Sub-District 58 - Ward 5   : Toronto West
Clinton Street, west side, from Harbord to Bloor Street.: Sub-District 65 - Ward 5   : Toronto West
```

Again, there may be other sections of the street that it does not list, because they are not described in the Ancestry descriptions.

Comment: I had perused your site which is a great resource. Unfortunately these Clinton Street entries are all south of Bloor Street. Are you aware of a polling station map for Toronto?